# What is /usr/bin/[?

Tags: linux, shell, command, test

I was just poking around in /usr/bin and I found an ELF binary file called `[`. `/usr/bin/[`. I have never heard of this file and my first thought was that it was a clever way of hiding a program, possibly a trojan. However it's present on all my CentOS servers and seems to have no manual entry. I can hazard a guess as to what it is but I was looking for a more authoritative answer...

Answer (score 29, accepted):

It's an alternative form of the 'test' command. Mostly used in scripts.

i.e.

```
if [ $VAR ]
then
    echo $VAR exists!
fi
```

Comment: But unlike test it requires the last arg to be a ]

Comment: Thanks. That's what I figured but I was surprised because I thought [ was a bash builtin

Comment: `[` *is* a bash builtin, but so is `test`.

not all shells are created equal — in plenty of them, `test` (and `[`) aren’t builtins.

Comment: There is a bash built-in, or at least, my system is acting as though there is. [ --help gives different input than /usr/bin/[ --help

Comment: test and [ are builtin to bash, but not necessarily all other shells.  You could temporarily move out of the path and run a bash script that uses either and you will see that the script still works.

Comment: Or try `type -a [` which will show that `[` is a Bash builtin and `/usr/bin/[`. The order shown is the order of preference.

Comment: This must be the most upvoted string of comments ever, lol.

Comment: `[ $VAR ]` fails when `$VAR` is empty or not set. Use `[ "$VAR" ]` instead.

Comment: @Josh: once upon another millennium, the Bourne shell did not have the test operator built in.  It was a regular command like any other; and /bin/test was linked to /bin/[ to give notational convenience.

Comment: This encapsulates everything I despise about software.

Answer (score 10):

It's what you call when you are using something like

```
if [ -e foo ]; then ...
```

in a shell script (but most shells have it as a buildin this days). *man test* should give you the docs.

Comment: I would accept your answer but Zypher beat you to it by a few seconds... sorry :-)

Answer (score 5):

As others pointed out, `[` is the shell's condition evaluation utility - test.

In fact, there is a manual page for that!

> $ man [

should give you more details about the opening square bracket.

Btw, in OS X, `[` is located in `/bin/[` :)